# How to read $[G:N]$?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

For a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, the quotient group of $N$ in $G$ is written $G/N$.

I could find from [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuotientGroup.html) how to read $G/N$ ("$G$ modulo $N$" or "$G$ mod $N$"), but I couldn't find $[G:N]$ (the order of $G/N$).

How to read $[G:N]$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The index of $N$ in $G$". That notation does not require normality (it can be seen as the number of *left* cosets of $N$, for instance), and the number it represents might of course be infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer.

Comment: Even in the case that the number of left and right cosets of N isn't equal, does symbol [G:N] stands for both of the cases? Thank you

Comment: @Edi The _number_ of left cosets and right cosets are the same, although if $N$ isn't normal the cosets themselves are different.